# How to remove the last character from a textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an IPad  application in which i am adding a calc type keypad,with 9 numerics and one back button .With all numerics i am upending the value of the text field like this `[number setText:[number.text stringByAppendingString:@"number"]];`.Now in the backtrace action i need to remove the last added value. I have tried this `[number.text substringToIndex:[number.text length]-2];` But with no luck.Can anybody help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
if ( [number.text length] > 0)
        number.text = [number.text substringToIndex:[number.text length] - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the result of your substringToIndex?

You'd need something like,

```
[number setText:[number.text substringToIndex:[number.text length]-2]];
```